# How can I use Delay method and await?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I want a sequence in my program to take a break for a while before going ahead with next operation.  Like this:

```
string s = HD.Text;

if (s.Contains("php")||s.Contains("echo"))
{ 
    HD.Text = "this okay ?";
    MessageBox.Show("Its Php ?","Gus"); 
}
```

I tried this:

```
if (s.Contains("php")||s.Contains("echo"))
{
   HD.Text = "this php ?";
   Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
   MessageBox.Show("Its Php ?","Guss"); 
}
```

But it doesn't work. It's throwing the exception below:

```
Cannot find type System.Resources.ResourceSet in module mscorlib.dll
```

Comment: This is Image : http://i.stack.imgur.com/cQBfB.jpg

Comment: That error you are getting has nothing to do with async/await

Comment: @ScottChamberlain so what i have to do  ** :( **

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Servy is saying, you need to ***await*** the task like this:

**Solution 1:**

```
public async Task Do()
{
   if (s.Contains("php")||s.Contains("echo"))
   { 
        HD.Text = "this php ?";
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        MessageBox.Show("Its Php ?","Guss"); 
   }
}
```

OR ***wait*** the task like this.

**Solution 2:**

```
public void Do()
{
   if (s.Contains("php")||s.Contains("echo"))
   { 
        HD.Text = "this php ?";
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Wait();
        MessageBox.Show("Its Php ?","Guss"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: But don't forget to mark your method by the **async** keyword.

Comment: @LukasKubis will i put Async inside      `  public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            string s = HD.Text;

                if (s.Contains("php")||s.Contains("echo"))
                { 

                   HD.Text = "this php ?";
                   Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                   MessageBox.Show("Its Php ?","Guss"); 
                }  `

Comment: Or you can change await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); to Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Wait();

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim if you want to use **await** in method body, then you have to mark the method by the **async** keyword.

Comment: @LukasKubis put tiny example please :(  i tried this :3  `  String s = HD.Text;  
            if (s.Contains("Php")||s.Contains("echo")){
                HD.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)).Wait();
                HD.Text = "Nice Shoot";
                HD.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;



            } `

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim look at the **Solution 2** of Rikard's answer. You can see there how to use async - await.

Answer (score 2):

`Task.Delay` *returns a `Task`* that will be completed after the given period of time.  If you just ignore that task, then you've effectively done nothing.  *Starting* the task takes basically no time.

If you `await` the `Task` returned from `Delay` then the rest of your code won't run until after that `Task` actually completes.

Comment: Neat answer; I'd edit the question before though, it's not too well formatted.